# Find common characters in output stream

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, grep

I have output of a command which goes like this:

```
/user/bin/this_text_area_islands[0]
/user/bin/this_text_area_seas[0]
/user/bin/this_text_area_volcanoes[0]
/user/bin/this_text_area_continents[0]
```

I want to pipe this and get common characters across the output stream:

```
/user/bin/this_text_area_[0]
```

One more example:

```
/user/bin/this_text_area_islands
/user/bin/this_drawing_area_seas
/user/bin/this_paint_area_volcanoes
/user/bin/this_play_area_continents
```

should output something like: [just match all common characters across all lines]

```
/user/bin/this_area_
```

Comment: Do you mean 'all common words'? How do you define a 'character'? What have you tried?

Comment: I mean all common literal characters : \w / etc if we traverse from left to right on each line, need to be preserved.

Comment: It should be `/user/bin/this_area_s`

Comment: Yeah sorry about that miss. 
Can this be achieved ? Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it works in all cases, but the following fits your examples:

```
#! /bin/bash

FIRST=$(head -1 $1)
LNB=$(wc -l < $1)

keepright () {
  M=$FIRST
  while [ -n "$M" ]
  do
    M=${M%?}
    [ $(fgrep -c "$M" "$1") -eq $LNB ] && break
  done
}

keepleft () {
  M=$FIRST
  while [ -n "$M" ]
  do
    M=${M#?}
    [ $(fgrep -c "$M" "$1") -eq $LNB ] && break
  done
}

keepright $1; printf "%s" "$M"
keepleft $1; printf "%s\n" "$M"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am a newbie so just need a bit help on how to use above code snippet on a linux command output. I was expecting something one-liner in which I can pipe my data output stream.
Do i need to store it in some file <file>.csh and then source it .
Sorry, it sounds a bit dumb but I need a bit of help here  :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: save the code as a file, say `filter.sh`, then `chmod +x filter.sh`, then you can use it in your ouput pipe command